# Homography, inliers/ Emgu CV/ SURF in C#

Tags: c#, surf, computer-vision

How can I get inliers/outliers of matched kyepoints using homography or some other method in C#?

I am working on SURF example provided on http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SURF_feature_detector_in_CSharp.

I got matchedFeature.  Code uses HomographyMatrix (homography). I want to separate inliers and outliers.

In C++:

```
bgroup({findFundamentalMat})

int cvFindFundamentalMat(const CvMat* points1, const CvMat* points2, 
    CvMat* fundamentalMatrix, int method=CV_FM_RANSAC, double param1=1., 
    double param2=0.99, CvMat* status=NULL)
```

returns inliers. Can I see similiar code also in C#.

Again I just need outliers/inliers separation.

Comment: What? This question is a mess. There's a comment that's not even part of your code. And it's very unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not so clear because if you are using emgucv homography computation is estimated using `CameraCalibration.FindHomography()` function using RANSAC if  there are more than 10 matching pairs.
I'm working on these topics for my thesis so i will post some relevant code that should fully reply to you and serve also to others.

```
result = MatchingRefinement.VoteForSizeAndOrientation(result, 1.5, 20);
homography = MatchingRefinement.
    GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(result, 
        HomographyDirection.DIRECT, HOMOGRAPHY_METHOD.LMEDS);
inverseHomography = MatchingRefinement.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(
    result, HomographyDirection.INVERSE, HOMOGRAPHY_METHOD.LMEDS);

PointF[] pts1 = new PointF[result.Length];
PointF[] pts1_t = new PointF[result.Length];
PointF[] pts2 = new PointF[result.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    pts1[i] = result[i].ObservedFeature.KeyPoint.Point;
    pts1_t[i] = result[i].ObservedFeature.KeyPoint.Point;
    pts2[i] = result[i].SimilarFeatures[0].Feature.KeyPoint.Point;
}

// Project model features according to homography
homography.ProjectPoints(pts1_t);

Image<Bgr, Byte> finalCorrespondance = inputImage.Copy();

matchedInliersFeatures = new List<MatchedImageFeature>();

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < pts1_t.Length; i1++)
{
    if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(pts2[i1].X - pts1_t[i1].X, 2d) + 
        Math.Pow(pts2[i1].Y - pts1_t[i1].Y, 2d)) <4d) // Inlier
    {
        PointF p_t = pts1_t[i1];
        PointF p = pts1[i1];
        finalCorrespondance.Draw(new CircleF(p, 2f), 
            new Bgr(Color.Yellow), 2);
        finalCorrespondance.Draw(new CircleF(p_t, 2f), 
            new Bgr(Color.Black), 2);
        finalCorrespondance.Draw(new LineSegment2DF(p, p_t), 
            new Bgr(Color.Blue), 1);

        MatchedImageFeature feature = new MatchedImageFeature();
        feature.SimilarFeatures = new SimilarFeature[] { 
            result[i1].SimilarFeatures[0] 
        };
        feature.ObservedFeature = result[i1].ObservedFeature;
        matchedInliersFeatures.Add(feature);
    }
}

List<ImageFeature> inliers = new List<ImageFeature>();
foreach (MatchedImageFeature match in matchedInliersFeatures)
{
    inliers.Add(match.ObservedFeature);
    inliers.Add(match.SimilarFeatures[0].Feature);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want inliers/outliers separation and you already have your matches try this:

```
//**RANSAC OUTLIER REMOVAL **//
Mat status;
vector<Point2f> trainMatches;
vector<Point2f> queryMatches;
vector<DMatch> inliers; 

    for( int i = 0; i < goodmatches.size(); i++ )
    {
        //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
        trainMatches.push_back( cv::Point2f(keypointsB[ goodmatches[i].trainIdx ].pt.x/640.0f, keypointsB[ goodmatches[i].trainIdx ].pt.y/480.0f) );
        queryMatches.push_back( cv::Point2f(keypointsA[ goodmatches[i].queryIdx ].pt.x/640.0f, keypointsA[ goodmatches[i].queryIdx ].pt.y/480.0f) );
    }   

    Mat _homography;    
    Mat h = cv::findHomography(trainMatches,queryMatches,CV_RANSAC,0.005, status);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < queryMatches.size(); i++) 
    {
        if(status.at<char>(i) != 0) 
        {
            inliers.push_back(goodmatches[i]);
        }
    }
```

Note that I normalized the points so Homography estimation is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `cvFindFundamentalMat` in C# would look like this:

```
int cvFindFundamentalMat(CvMat points1, CvMat points2, CvMat fundamentalMatrix, 
     CV_FM method, double param1, double param2, CvMat status);
```

Parameter defaults was introduced in C# 4.0. I assume that Emgu CV does not support .Net 4.0 yet (correct me if I'm wrong), thus an overload providing the default values could be made:

```
int cvFindFundamentalMat(CvMat points1, CvMat points2, CvMat fundamentalMatrix)
{
    return cvFindFundamentalMat(points1, points2, fundamentalMatrix,
           CV_FM.CV_FM_RANSAC, 1.0, 0.99, null);
}
```

Note: as commenters also have stated, it is hard to be sure what you're asking for. Here, I have just guessed that some of your question is how the provided C++ code would look like in C#.

Comment: Thanx, for this help. I need explaination why you are using status (Null). I have in example PointF format of points. Do I have to make matrix from them. Matrix<float> circles = new Matrix<float>(length, 1, 2);  or Matrix<float> circles = new Matrix<float>(length, 2, 1);

Comment: status==null was just because the default value from the C++ signature was null.

Comment: But yes, if you have `PointF` data you would have to convert them into a `CvMat` structure first.